# Google Hangouts API Max Connections

Tags: google-hangouts

I had read online that Google supports up to 15 connections for hangouts. I'm building a web app that will require around 50 video connections wherein 50 users will be connected to the session, with around 4 or 5 users' streams being displayed at any one time. Is it possible to expand  Google's maximum number of connections? What are some workarounds?

Thanks!